# which xml validator will work perfectly for multithreading project

Tags: java, xml, schema

I have used jdom for xml validation against schema. The main problem there is that it gives an error

FWK005 parse may not be called while parsing

The main reason was that multiple of threads working for xerces validation at the same time. SO I got the solution that i have to lock that validation. which is not good

So I want to know which xml validator works perfectly for multithreading project

```
public static HashMap<String, String> validate(String xmlString, Validator validator) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        //obtain lock to proceed
//         lock.lock();

        try {
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
//                Source source = new DOMSource(builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes())));

            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            map.put("ISVALID", "TRUE");
            logger.info("We have successfuly validated the schema");
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("NOT2 VALID STRING IS :" + xmlString);
            map.put("MSG", ioe.getMessage());
            //         logger.error("IOException while validating the input XML", ioe);
        }
        logger.info(map);
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("XML VALIDATION TOOK:::" + (t2 - t1));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
        //release lock
//         lock.unlock();
        builder = null;
    }

    return map;
}
```

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think any of the java xml validators are threadsafe.  Options are to:

1. Create a new instance each time you need to validate
2. Create a pool of validators that you pull from
3. Make use of ThreadLocal to cache validators

Comment: +1 - but the first option should be simply to create a new validator each time you need one.  (The existing options are performance optimizations, and should only be considered if you *know for sure* that creation of validator instances will be a performance bottleneck.)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about multi-threaded XML validation... take note of this bug in java 1.6: [javax.xml.validation.Schema is not thread safe](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6773084)

The Schema class javadoc claims it is thread-safe, but this was not the case in some versions of java. The result is unexpected validation errors when you try to run two validations simultaneously.

The workaround suggested on the bug report is to use a newer version of the xerces library.