# Multiple jersey-clients with clashing responses from Single tomcat server

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jersey-client

I have a single tomcat server running on port localhost:8080
**When I run multiple threads/request against the server, every once in a while the responses to those requests clash**. What I mean is that if Alice and Bob send out requests, Alice might get the response belonging to Bob and vice versa. Also, every once in a while Alice and Bob might both get Alice's request. See example below. Note: this only happens like 3% of the time, but 3% out of 2000+ requests is a lot of failures.

1. Alice -> sendRequest1
2. Bob   -> sendRequest2
3. Alice -> receiveResponse2
4. Bob   -> receiveResponse1

**My question is, Why does this happen and Is there a way around it?**

Perhaps there is something in the configuration I am missing.

---

Here is some more info so that I can cover the basic questions.
I am using the Jersey api client to talk to the server (com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource)
which is supposedly thread safe (at least thats what it claims)

This is NOT a threading problem. 1) I have verified that each thread has its own instance of the client. 2) I ran multiple processes (all single threaded) at the same time and found the same results.

I ran them with one thread on the server side and the clashing still happened.

Here is my catalina configuration (in the server.xml file)

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="0" maxSpareThreads="5"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

From what I understand about HTTP, a new port is opened (or reused) on each request. The server is then supposed to send the response the the exact port the request came from. If this is the case, then no clashing should happen.

Comment: What is your web application doing? How do you know that a response is intended for another client?

Comment: This does not sound like a config problem to me - this sounds like a server side threading issue. The server will only be threadsafe if your code is threadsafe. Do you have any shared state ( static variables are the classic case ) in your processing classes? ( which are servlets I presume? )

Comment: I am running "tests" and one situation where I have narrowed this down occurs when the same call (with different data) is sent. Call A checks to make sure an error is thrown, call B should be successful. But A will say "did not receive expected error" and B will say "Unexpected error occurred". I am open to suggestions if you have a way I can absolutely verify the responses are getting crossed.

Comment: @DaveHowes This is not a server threading issue. I Tried running the server with only 1 thread to see if that was the case. However, even when the server only has one thread, this issue still exists.

Comment: So you have one instance of the client, running in a single thread, and this problem manifests itself? I'm not sure I understand - what do you mean by "even when the server only has one thread" - how have you configured the server so that it processes the requests in a single thread?

Comment: Post the server-side code

Comment: The server code is not mine. However what I mean by "even when the server only has one thread" is that I set the Catalina configuration to maxThreads="1". This should limit the server to have a threadpool the size of 1, correct?
I still have multiple clients hitting the one server, just there is only one thread answering those clients.

Comment: If you have multiple client side processes running, each single threaded and each ( presumeably ) in their own JVM and you see this behaviour, then I think it is safe to say that you have discovered that the server side code has a bug.

Comment: So that is what I figured. But after running the server with 1 thread I was confused. Turns out that the server is creating extra threads on top of what tomcat is telling it too. So controlling the threads through tomcat wasnt doing quite what I expected. Thank you all for your input however.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the answer really lies with the XML validator on the server side. 
I found this discussion helpful.

[which xml validator will work perfectly for multithreading project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665748/which-xml-validator-will-work-perfectly-for-multithreading-project)